# "What is causing this 'incorrect form submission' response to my simple node post request?"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

Making a signup page for an app I'm going to build later. Just created a simple as can be node server, and it's running on port 3000. I created a React app with a simple form interface, running on port 3001. The user fills in the form and hits the register button, and this should send an email and password to the post route of /register.

But I get "incorrect form submission" every time. It looks like just a json object in the network pane "{email: dummy@email, password: 123}", so I'm not sure what this means...

```
onSubmitRegister = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

The node server looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello");
})

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

For now, I just want it to console log the req.body, so I know everything is working OK before I go on to build a MongoDB database and start adding documents to collections. Stack Overflow and other forum threads I've googled suggest checking the headers are correct. This looks OK to me. Am I missing something?

EDIT: This is what the form looks like, the entire render function:

```
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <div className="text-center">
        <form className="form-signin">
          <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Ohaii Sign Up</h1>
          <label for="inputEmail" className="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="inputEmail"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Email address"
              required=""
              autofocus=""
              onChange={this.onEmailChange}
            />
          <label for="inputPassword" className="sr-only">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="inputPassword"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
            required=""/>
          <label for="inputPassword" className="sr-only">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="confirmPassword"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            required=""
            onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
          />
          <div className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" style={{'color': '#fff'}}>
            <span className="fa fa-google"></span> Sign Up with Google
          </div>
          <div className="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" style={{'color': '#fff'}}>
            <span className="fa fa-facebook"></span> Sign Up with Facebook
          </div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={this.onSubmitRegister}
        className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
      >Register</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Are you using `e.preventDefault` in `onSubmitRegister` to stop the submission of the form?

Comment: I've actually just got a button outside the form that makes the request using the email and password stored on this.state. The submit button inside the form was just refreshing the page and no POST request was being logged in the terminal.

Comment: Can you include the React form which you have built in the question?

Comment: No problem. Just added it to the original question.

Comment: Check 2 things here, first, console the data before sending, second, does the POST in capital works or not? not sure why this is happening

Comment: Tried POST in capitals just now, but I doubt it's that, since the network panel clearly shows a POST request is being attempted, upper or lower case. Console logged the data that's being sent, it doesn't look like anything unexpected: {"email":"hello@hello.com","password":"123"}. 

Thanks for your time anyway. I feel better someone else is as stumped at this as me. :)

Comment: Are you sure about the error? because you are not submitting the form, you are just sending the data to the server from outside. So how can the browser say that "incorrect form submission"

Comment: It's definitely what it says. Bad Request 400. Response: "Incorrect form submission". And you're right, that's what's so confusing about it. The fact that it's a form is irrelevant. I'm just using the state on the component to get the values and then I'm sending a request with the fetch API. The form shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: @WebDevKun It's historical. The POST method was created for form submissions (ajax did not exist when it was created and forms did not exist before it was created - forms and POST was created simultaneously). So a POST request implies a browser form submission. The server can not distinguish weather you actually used a form submit or some other method (fetch, XMLHttpRequest etc) to perform a POST request therefore assumes it was a form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a problem specific to my environment. Just cleared the npm cache and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending JSON data (both your body is JSON and you are setting the JSON content type), I would recommend to change the bodyParser middleware to:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

At least, in my quick test I was then able to send data from the browser and saw it on the server. With `bodyParser.urlencoded` that was not the case, however, I did not get the same error as you did.

In addition, you should return some response from the server, for example, I used:

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.end("{}");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my machine for some reason but I compressed the code and sent it to someone over Discord and it works on his. So I really don't know what's wrong anymore >_< There must be some screw up with my environment. Will try reinstalling node.